# Eclipse failing to see Gradle provided jar

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

We have a Gradle project that I'm trying to use in Eclipse.
After other users made changes and I had to do a Gradle Refresh, Eclipse now can't compile the project.

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for
   org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate. Fix the build path then try building this project   

The type org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate cannot be resolved. It is indirectly 
  referenced from required .class files RabbitMQConfig.java /Account/src/main/java/com/efi/metrix/config    line 1  Java Problem
```

If I use Ctrl-T, I can see the class and what jar it is in.  The jar IS in the classpath and can be seen under the "Project and External Dependencies" section in Package Explorer.

I've tried deleting the jar and re-running Gradle Refresh, which downloads the jar again, and I get the same error with the build failing.  I've also tried an Eclipse Clean on the project.
(I did try restarting eclipse as well.)

Any hints on what might be causing this?

Comment: Not really an answer, but we were able to get it working by using STS4 instead of regular Eclipse.
Of course, not all our current non-spring projects will compile properly in STS4, so we now have to use 2 different editors.
PITA

Comment: Well, just found out a weird incompatibility.
In Eclipse - Preferences - Java Compiler - Errors/Warnings - Null analysis
if we turn off "inherit null annotations", it will find RetryTemplate and compile.
Of course, it also means that any subclass that was overriding a method that was annotated, now needs to be annotated directly rather than inheriting it.
Bit of a PITA.

Answer (score 0):

Finally tracked this down.
Eclipse project, Properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings
In the "Enable annotation-based null analysis" section, if you have "Inherit null annotations" enabled, you get the compile errors.
I turned off that option, and it now compiles without errors.